# Turn "abc" to "[97, 98 99]"

Tags: python

how can I change a string to a string of list (as seen in the question header)

I can simply do something like that, but I'm there is a simpler way

```
orig = "bla bla"
final = "["
for i in orig:
    final = "%s %d," % (final, i)
final = final[:-1] + "]"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also do:

```
>>> orig = "bla bla"
>>> str(map(ord, orig))
'[98, 108, 97, 32, 98, 108, 97]'
>>>
```

Comment: Yay for functional programming.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [ord](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord).

```
>>> nums = str([ord(char) for char in "abc"])
>>> nums
"[97, 98, 99]"
```

Comment: I guess OP requires a string of a list.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
>>> k = "abc"
>>> m = "{}".format([ord(elem) for elem in k])
>>> m
'[97, 98, 99]'
```

You could just do,

```
>>> m = str([ord(elem) for elem in k])
>>> m
'[97, 98, 99]'
```